# ggplot2: geom_vline to heatmap

Tags: r, dataframe

I created the below ggplot but I don't know how to highlight and to add 5 geom_vline() in my plot at: **04:00:00**, **08:00:00**,**12:00:00**,**16:00:00** and **20:00:00**? Is a way to do that? Also how to add the time to the x axis as I tried with x_continous but it does not work?

[image]

**Sample code**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=variable, fill=value)) +  
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightyellow", high="red") + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Date", title="", fill="") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1),  face="bold", size=16, color="black") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1),  face="bold", size=16, color="black") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

**Sample data:** Selected only the first 300

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 
    10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 
    27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 34200, 36000, 37800, 39600, 41400, 
    43200, 45000, 46800, 48600, 50400, 52200, 54000, 55800, 57600, 
    59400, 61200, 63000, 64800, 66600, 68400, 70200, 72000, 73800, 
    75600, 77400, 79200, 81000, 82800, 84600, 86400, 1800, 3600, 
    5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 
    23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 34200, 36000, 37800, 
    39600, 41400, 43200, 45000, 46800, 48600, 50400, 52200, 54000, 
    55800, 57600, 59400, 61200, 63000, 64800, 66600, 68400, 70200, 
    72000, 73800, 75600, 77400, 79200, 81000, 82800, 84600, 86400, 
    1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 
    19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 34200, 
    36000, 37800, 39600, 41400, 43200, 45000, 46800, 48600, 50400, 
    52200, 54000, 55800, 57600, 59400, 61200, 63000, 64800, 66600, 
    68400, 70200, 72000, 73800, 75600, 77400, 79200, 81000, 82800, 
    84600, 86400, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 
    16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 
    32400, 34200, 36000, 37800, 39600, 41400, 43200, 45000, 46800, 
    48600, 50400, 52200, 54000, 55800, 57600, 59400, 61200, 63000, 
    64800, 66600, 68400, 70200, 72000, 73800, 75600, 77400, 79200, 
    81000, 82800, 84600, 86400, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 
    12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 25200, 27000, 
    28800, 30600, 32400, 34200, 36000, 37800, 39600, 41400, 43200, 
    45000, 46800, 48600, 50400, 52200, 54000, 55800, 57600, 59400, 
    61200, 63000, 64800, 66600, 68400, 70200, 72000, 73800, 75600, 
    77400, 79200, 81000, 82800, 84600, 86400, 1800, 3600, 5400, 7200, 
    9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 21600, 23400, 
    25200, 27000, 28800, 30600, 32400, 34200, 36000, 37800, 39600, 
    41400, 43200, 45000, 46800, 48600, 50400, 52200, 54000, 55800, 
    57600, 59400, 61200, 63000, 64800, 66600, 68400, 70200, 72000, 
    73800, 75600, 77400, 79200, 81000, 82800, 84600, 86400, 1800, 
    3600, 5400, 7200, 9000, 10800, 12600, 14400, 16200, 18000, 19800, 
    21600), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), variable = c("02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", 
    "02/01/2019", "02/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", "03/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", 
    "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "04/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", 
    "05/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", 
    "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "06/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", 
    "07/01/2019", "07/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", 
    "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", 
    "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019", "08/01/2019"), value = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your `geom_vline`s by converting the vector of times to `hms` format using `lubridate::hms` and passing the result to the `xintercept` argument of `geom_vline`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=variable, fill=value)) +  
  geom_tile() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = lubridate::hms(c("04:00:00", "08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00", "20:00:00"))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightyellow", high="red") + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Date", title="", fill="") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1),  face="bold", size=16, color="black") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1),  face="bold", size=16, color="black") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your time. I don't know how to highlight on the x-axis "04:00:00", "08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00", "20:00:00", it does not work with x_continous. Alos why is the white gap between the x and y-axis?

Comment: Try with `scale_x_time(breaks = lubridate::hms(c("04:00:00", "08:00:00","12:00:00","16:00:00", "20:00:00")))`

Comment: I tried scale_x_continous() and it did not work

Comment: is there a way to have the date in increasing order and not in decreasing one?

Comment: As your dates are characters you could try with `fct_rev(variable)`. That will work for your example data. BTW: You could remove the white space by using `scale_x_time(..., expand=c(0,0))` and `scale_y_discrete(..., expand = ...)`. That will remove the default expansion of the scale added by ggplot2.